# How to fix data is getting repeated on clicking save button c#

Tags: c#, winforms

1. `Form1` code

   ```
   namespace passl {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
           public Form1()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
               sidepanel.Height = btnuser.Height;
               personaldetail2.BringToFront();
           }

           private void btnuser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               sidepanel.Height = btnuser.Height;
               personaldetail2.BringToFront();
           }

           private void btnedu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               sidepanel.Height = btnedu.Height;
               educationaldetail2.BringToFront();
           }

           private void btnprint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
              // print on new form 
               Form2 f2 = new Form2();
               f2.Show();
           }

           private void btnuserdetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               raiseUpdate();
           }

           public delegate void UpdateDelegate(object sender, UpdateEventArgs args);
           public static event UpdateDelegate UpdateEventHandler;

           public class UpdateEventArgs : EventArgs
           {
               public string txt1Data { get; set; }
               public string txt2Data { get; set; }
               public string txt3Data { get; set; }
               public string txt4Data { get; set; }
           }

           protected void raiseUpdate()
           {
               UpdateEventArgs args = new UpdateEventArgs();
               args.txt1Data = personaldetail2.TextBox1.Text;
               args.txt2Data = personaldetail2.TextBox2.Text;
               args.txt3Data = educationaldetail2.TextBox1.Text;
               args.txt4Data = educationaldetail2.TextBox2.Text;
               UpdateEventHandler.Invoke(this, args);
           }
       } 
   }
   ```
2. `Form2` code

   ```
   namespace passl {
       public partial class Form2 : Form
       {
           public Form2()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
               Form1.UpdateEventHandler += F1_UpdateEventHandler;
           }

           private void F1_UpdateEventHandler(object sender, Form1.UpdateEventArgs args)
           {
               label1.Text += "NAME  : " + args.txt1Data + Environment.NewLine;
               label2.Text += "EMAIL : " + args.txt2Data + Environment.NewLine;
               label3.Text += "SSC : " + args.txt3Data + Environment.NewLine;
               label4.Text += "HSC: " + args.txt4Data + Environment.NewLine;    
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. code `usercontrol` -> `personaldetails2`

   ```
   namespace passl.usercontrols {
       public partial class personaldetail : UserControl
       {
           public personaldetail()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }

           public TextBox TextBox1
           {
               get { return textBox1; }
               set { textBox1 = value; }
           }

           public TextBox TextBox2
           {
               get { return textBox2; }
               set { textBox2 = value; }
           }

       }
   }
   ```
4. code `usercontrol` -> `educationaldetails2`

   ```
   namespace passl.usercontrols {
       public partial class personaldetail : UserControl
       {
           public personaldetail()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }

           public TextBox TextBox1
           {
               get { return textBox1; }
               set { textBox1 = value; }
           }

           public TextBox TextBox2
           {
               get { return textBox2; }
               set { textBox2 = value; }
           }

       }
   }
   ```

   The program is working but on click of save button n number of times
   the data is duplicating it should show only once on `form2`

   This is the image below issue in this pls fix

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nwFq.png

Comment: In `F1_UpdateEventHandler` you are setting `Text` using `+=` but perhaps you intend `=`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `+=` to just `=`. It will get overridden by the most recent button click.

```
private void F1_UpdateEventHandler(object sender, Form1.UpdateEventArgs args)
{
    label1.Text = "NAME  : " + args.txt1Data + Environment.NewLine;
    label2.Text = "EMAIL : " + args.txt2Data + Environment.NewLine;
    label3.Text = "SSC : " + args.txt3Data + Environment.NewLine;
    label4.Text = "HSC: " + args.txt4Data + Environment.NewLine;    
}
```